# IIS 7, ASP.NET: AccessViolationException

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, access-violation

What can be the reason of the following exception in ASP.NET application under IIS 7?
It is an unhandled exception that restarts the whole application.

**Exception:** System.AccessViolationException

**Message:** Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory has been corrupted.

**StackTrace:**

```
   in System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIsLastNotification(IntPtr pRequestContext, RequestNotificationStatus dwStatus)
   in System.Web.HttpRuntime.FinishRequestNotification(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context, RequestNotificationStatus& status)
   in System.Web.HttpRuntime.OnRequestNotificationCompletionHelper(IAsyncResult ar)
   in System.Web.HttpRuntime.OnRequestNotificationCompletion(IAsyncResult ar)
   in System.Web.HttpAsyncResult.Complete(Boolean synchronous, Object result, Exception error, RequestNotificationStatus status)
   in System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)
   in System.Web.HttpApplication.ResumeStepsWaitCallback(Object error)
   in System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   in System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallbackInternal(_ThreadPoolWaitCallback tpWaitCallBack)
   in System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback(Object state)
```

**[UPD]**

**System:** Windows Web Server 2008 64-bit.

**Application details:** ASP.NET application that doesn't use pages architecture. It process requests using custom http sync and async handlers. There are also parallel threads from ThreadPool or created by Thread class are running.

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem? I have the same issue and cannot find any solution.

Comment: Sorry to bother you, do you have any ideas? What was the issue in your situation?

Answer (score 1):

I experience this issue when my `IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest()` function returns while I still have an ongoing `WriteAsync()` or `FlushAsync()` operation on `HttpResponse` or `HttpResponse.OutputStream` (i.e., when I have not awaited the `Task` returned from those functions).

While your question was written before async/await was introduced to C#, so you wouldn't have been using those keywords, it does sound like you were doing a lot of asynchronous operations (async handlers, parallel threads, etc.), so I bet there is a good chance that this is the same underlying issue that you experienced.

In some cases it might simply be a bug that your request handler does not ensure that the `WriteAsync()` or `FlushAsync()` operation completes, and the code fix should simply be to ensure that you wait for the operation's completion before returning from `ProcessRequest()`. However, in my case, I am wrapping the `WriteAsync()` or `FlushAsync()` `Task` in some custom timeout logic and am intentionally not awaiting the underlying `Task` in the case that the client does not respond promptly.

On my local machine (Windows 1809, .NET 4.7.2), it seems that I can keep my custom timeout logic while avoiding this AccessViolationException by calling `HttpContext.Request.Abort()` when I don't want to wait for the `WriteAsync()` or `FlushAsync()` operation to complete. However, this fix does not appear to work on some Windows Server 2016 or 2012 R2 servers that I tested on. So, there is a possibility the behavior has changed in more recent Windows versions, though I'm not 100% sure that there isn't some other variable accounting for the difference in behavior between the machines that I have tested.

Answer (score 0):

A third-party ISAPI filter may cause this problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

I don't use any third-party filter. Pure ASP.NET application.

Answer (score 0):

A hardware error is occasionally the unexpected culprit in such cases. Everything may work perfectly, except one little method in one obscure DLL.

Or does this happen on multiple machines, as well? Try a different one.